# No outbound access to internet from Windows Server 2019 on VPC

Tags: nat, amazon-vpc, windows-server-2019

On AWS, I have a NAT instance (Linux) and a Webserver (Windows 2019) on a VPC. The web server works as it should, I can also RDP to the webserver via the nat, no issues. The problem is that there's no outbound access to the internet from the Webserver instance; after I RDP (as admin) I can't browse.

AWS Basic Network configuration:

VPC Network ACL: inbound: All Allowed, outbound: All Allowed

VPC is associated with an internet-gateway

VPC: 10.0.0.0/16

public subnet: 10.0.2.0/24

Private subnet: 10.0.1.0/24

NAT IP:  10.0.2.40

WEB IP:  10.0.1.128

Disabled source/destination check on NAT

security group on web server: inbound from nat-server and outbound All open.

security group on nat server: inbound from 80, web sg, and my IP, and outbound All open.

Network on NAT: IP forwarding is enabled, and since the web application works, I don't believe there's any issues here.

```
sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.2.40            tcp dpt:443 to:10.0.1.128
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.2.40            tcp dpt:80 to:10.0.1.128


Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  113235  7781297 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I can access the application served from Windows 2019 instance via the internet, the network seems to work in that respect.

I may need additional settings on the NAT, or Windows 2019, the only configuration I've done on Windows 2019 is setting up the IIS.

What do I need to check, and set, to have outbound internet browsing capability from the web server?

Comment: I also ran, port address translator that comes with the AMI, located: 
 /usr/local/sbin/configure-pat.sh

still no access...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. The private route table needed to set its target to the NAT instance.
Edit the Private Route, add:
0.0.0.0/0   target:  NAT-instance.

Public route should target the internet gateway, if not already set to do so.

It may also help to run the port address translator on the NAT, I believe my settings already supported that prior to running.

/usr/local/sbin/configure-pat.sh

Hope this helps someone, it kept me busy for a few days.